# Javascript solve linear equation with nerdamer.solveEquations

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, equation

I'm trynna make a javascript program who solves linear equations using nerdamer, I'm following nerdamer's documentation right [here](https://nerdamer.com/functions/solveEquations.html) but I got error when I tried to use function solveEquations
here's the code:

```
const nerdamer = require("nerdamer");
const eq = nerdamer.solveEquations(["3+x=9"]);
console.log(eq.toString());
```

here's the error I got:

```
const eq = nerdamer.solveEquations(["3+x=9"]);
                ^

TypeError: nerdamer.solveEquations is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `solveEquations`, you need to load the `Solve` module as well. But also note that `const` cannot be used since nerdamer gets modified when other modules are loaded.  For your example to work, do:

```js
var nerdamer = require("nerdamer")
require('nerdamer/Solve')

const eq = nerdamer.solveEquations(["3+x=9"])
console.log(eq.toString())
```

Example: https://runkit.com/61a67e5dd78be10008bf0fcc/61a67e5d000388000831e495

Or, if you'll be using all modules, you can use a single import:

```js
const nerdamer = require("nerdamer/all.min")
```

Here is the quick start guide: https://nerdamer.com/quickstart.html